# presentCodeRedemptionSheet() displays a View with List of Offer Codes

Tags: ios, swiftui, in-app-purchase, ios-simulator, storekit

In my Xcode I have created a Product.StoreKit and within that I have a subscription which has 3 Offer Codes.

In PaymentView I am trying to open a Redemption Sheet as follows:

```
if #available(iOS 14.0, *) { 
     paymentQueue.presentCodeRedemptionSheet() 
}
```

But the Redemption Sheet is Pre-populated with Offer Codes and instead of having a text field to enter Offer Code, user can simply choose from the list of offer codes. This is not an expected behavior.
[Offer Code Redemption Sheet Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKnjo.png)

I tried to use offerCodeRedemption(isPresented:onCompletion:) too but I had the same issue persisting.

```
.offerCodeRedemption(isPresented: $presentOfferCodeSheet) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success:
                print("***********Offer code redemption successful.")
                presentOfferCodeSheet = false
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Offer code redemption failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Was Dew correct that this behavior is somehow tied to the Xcode environment and things work correctly when the app is live on the App Store?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you have a XCode environment. It's normal behavior to test this promotions and manage them from StoreKit Xcode module. If you will upload your app on store (for example to Test Flight), you have a normal text input probably